# How to get IP address of any host without using the built in library function InetAddress.getbyName()?

Tags: java, sockets, dns

I am making my own Iterative DNSresolver, where I need the ip of the host to use... but Datagrampacket requires InetAddresstype object. So I had to use the library function.

```
InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(DNSAddress);
....
//some code
....
DatagramPacket dnsReqPacket = new DatagramPacket(dnsFrame, dnsFrame.length,             ip, DNSServerPort);
....
//some code
```

So, I was thinking is it possible to make my own getbyName() function without using the inetAddress library?

Comment: Yes, use JNDI with the DNS provider.

Comment: How to create a function that can give me same output as InetAddress library's getByName() function returns ? Is there any reference code? I just wanted to do it from scratch!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`java.net.InetAddress.getByAddress(byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByAddress(byte%5B%5D)).  It creates an `InetAddress` object from the raw (network) representation of the address.

The method is rather confusingly named because unlike [`gethostbyaddr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gethostbyaddr.3.html), it does *not* perform a reverse lookup:

> This method doesn't block, i.e. no reverse name service lookup is performed.

Using an `InetAddress` created using `getByAddress` together with `DatagramPacket` or `DatagramSocket` does not necessarily trigger name resolution, either, so there is no risk of infinite recursion (in case the Java implementation attempts to perform name resolution using your own DNS implementation).

Comment: I was asking if it's possible to do the same function "without using InetAddress library" .. I actually do no intend to use the library if possible.. Can I generate the IP that is to be passed as a argument in the DatagrapPacket by creating a socket myself or something like that?? Or is there code from scratch that is same as InetAddress library's getByName() function?

Comment: I assume you are worried about incorrect behavior/infinite loops if `InetAddress` itself uses DNS. For `getByAddress`, it does not do this. It is essentially is a not-so-thin wrapper against the raw `byte[]` address.